# Different contactTest bit masks on a single object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

Can one physics body object have two different contactTestBitMask? I'm making my first game in Objective-C but I have one object(player) that can collide with two different objects(object1 and object2) and do different things when colliding with one or another, so I have this line:

```
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = object1Category | object2Category;
```

But the thing is that when I use the `-didBeginContact` method, when the player collides with the `object1` does some code but when the player collides with the `object2` does the same code that when it collides with object1 and I want the player do some different code when collides with object2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your didBeginContact method you should have something like this:

```
if (collision == (CategoryObjectA | CategoryPlayer)) {
        // code...
}

if (collision == (CategoryObjectB | CategoryPlayer)) {
        // code...
}
```

Obviously you need to set a unique categoryBitMask for object A and for object B and also have their contactTestBitMask set to recognize the player object.

Comment: note: collision should be `contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask|contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask`

Comment: @Okapi - It's much simpler to simply have uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask); at the top of the didBeginContact method and continue with the code I have above.